# PHP Interface and func_get_args

Tags: php

How would I write an interface that would enforces the classes that implements it to use `func_get_args`?

Example:

```
interface SomeInterface{
    function somefunc(); // ???????
}

class SomeClass implements SomeInterface{
    function somefunc(){
        $args = func_get_args();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pray tell, what are you try to do?

Comment: Basically in the interface, i want to enforce the function to accept a variable amount of arguments.

Comment: can you elaborate this more in terms of its context? Like how will the `somefunc()` use the `func_get_args()`? Also, please use naming conventions, `somefunc()` could be `someFunc()`.

Comment: @ultimatebuster: you can't, since that's not how you define interfaces.  Interface functions "cannot contain body", as I'm sure you're aware by the error such an attempt would give.  So as blockhead said, what are you trying to do?  Perhaps someone can show you an alternative.

Comment: I'm just saying, somefunc will need to take a number of arguments as I will have to pass a number of arguments into it.

Comment: How you have it is correct if I understand what you are trying to do. Interface is not concerned with the arguments passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot in PHP. Document the function carefully in the interface.

Most interfaces should contain more lines of comments - explaining what the functions should do when implemented - than actual interface declarations.

Comment: The programmer implementing the interface *needs* the documentation to implement it. Add this special information to that documentation. Normal PHP doesn't interact with its own docblocks.

Answer (score 4):

An interface is pure design.  The interface doesn't care what its implementation is.

Answer (score 1):

```
interface SomeInterface{
    function func_get_args(); // ???????
}

class SomeClass implements SomeInterface{
    function func_get_args(){
        //Implement the code for the above function
    }
}
```

The above is the way to write the interface

Is that the one are you looking?

Comment: Yes that would implement the method, however you still haven't called the built in method func_get_args();

Comment: I am assuming he is new to interface and doesnot know how to write interface, so i have given him the clue